# Irreducible Representation of Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, invariant-subspace

Let $g$ be a lie algebra, and $V$ be a vector space over $F.$ Assume that $\operatorname{char} (F) =0,$ and $\dim(V)=n>1.$  I want to show that $(\rho, V)$ be in irreducible representation of $g$ iff $(\rho^*, V^*) $ is an irreducible representation of $g$. Note that here $\rho^*$ is the contagradient representation of $\rho,$ and its defined as $\rho^*(X)(f) = -f(\rho(X)$ for any functional $f \in V^*.$

I was able to prove that if $(\rho^*, V^*)$ is irreducible, then so is $(\rho, V).$ I proved it using contradiction. I spent a fair amount of time to do the other direction, but I am completely stuck. Could you help me with the other direction? Thanks so much.

Comment: Show that $V$ is the dual representation of $V^{\ast}$.

Comment: I did not use finite dimensionality so far. Could you give an example that shows that converse is false without the finite-dimensionality? I know that V and V* are isomorphic, but still, I cannot proceed. Thanks.

Comment: For example, $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ has various-dimensional simple modules given by various Verma modules (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verma_module) and because they are countable-dimensional their duals are uncountable-dimensional. But a simple module for an at-most-countable-dimensional Lie algebra is necessarily at-most-countable-dimensional (exercise).

Comment: @James: You mean that $V$ and $V^{**}$ are isomorphic. ($V$ and $V^*$ are not isomorphic as representations in general.) Once you have that, and you have "$W^*$ irreducible $\implies$ $W$ irreducible", you should be done, just apply it to $W=V^*$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, the problem is solved.